# Delete action in AngularJS app wired onto Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm working on a "To-Do List" application, built on AngularJS sitting on Ruby on Rails.

Now I'm trying to setup a delete button, "X" to remove 'to-do' items that will **persist to the db**.

I haven't found many Angular on ROR examples online so I'm kindof lost on making it work.

Current error when clicking on a delete button in view is https://.../todos/6.json 404 (Not Found)

I've attached what i think is relevant code i've worked on so far. Any advice would be very appreciated!

**_home.html**

```
<div ng-repeat="todo in todos">
    {{todo.desc}}
    <button type="button" ng-click="removeTodo(todo.id)" class="close">&times;</button>
</div>
```

**mainCtrl.js**

```
angular.module('App')
.controller('MainCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    'todos',
    function($scope, todos) {
        $scope.todos = todos.todos;

        $scope.removeTodo = function(id) {
            todos.delete(id);
        };
    }]);
```

**todos.js**

```
angular.module('App')
.factory('todos', ['$http', function($http) {
    var o = {
        todos : []
    };

    o.delete = function(id) {
        return $http.delete('/todos/' + id + '.json').success(function(data) {
            o.todos.delete(data);
        })
    }   
    return o;
}])
```

**schema.rb**

```
  create_table "todos", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "desc"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'application#angular'
  resources :todos, only: [:create, :index, :show, :delete]
end
```

**todos_controller.rb**

```
class TodosController < ApplicationController
    def delete
        respond_with Todo.find(params[:id])
    end

    private
    def todo_params
        params.require(:todo).permit(:desc)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Oleg for giving advice regarding routes.rb and todos_controller.rb.

I decided to continue using ajax with $http. After fixing above, and the following two changes, it was able to persist to db, and update in browser.

1. .factory

   ```
   o.delete = function(id) {
       return $http.delete('/todos/' + id + '.json').success(function(data) {
           for (var i = o.todos.length -1; i >=0; i--) {
               if(o.todos[i].id === id) {
                   o.todos.splice(i, 1);
               }
           }
       })
   }
   ```
2. mainCtrl

   ```
   $scope.removeTodo = function(todo) {
       todos.delete(todo.id);
   };
   ```

Answer (score 1):

1. why you use AJAX? Use [Angular's $resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource), there already present method delete (remove)
2. according to [Rails CRUD](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions) your action should named `destroy`

   ```
   Rails.application.routes.draw do
     root to: 'application#angular'
     resources :todos, only: [:create, :index, :show, :destroy]
   end
   ```

and in controller

```
def destroy
  .....
```

3. even in your `delete` action you just find record, but don't `destroy` it:

   respond_with Todo.destroy(params[:id])

instead

```
respond_with Todo.find(params[:id])
```

Comment: Super appreciated your feedback. In response to why use $http - i understand that $resource is built ontop of $http, so i wanted to first become comfortable with $http. Not a good idea?